# pvrtc compression on osx

Tags: macos, image-processing, osx-snow-leopard, pvrtc

I am working on an OpenGL app on MAC OSX 10.6.x. I want to compress raw pixel data in the OpenGL app using PVRTC. Is there a PVRTC library for OSX that can help me?

Appreciate any pointers and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a command-line tool called `texturetool` that ships with the SDK.  See [Using texturetool to Compress Textures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TextureTool/TextureTool.html).  You might also find useful tools included with [the PowerVR Insider SDK](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-sdk.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was an osx library that we could compile into the app.

Comment: The PowerVR SDK does appear to have an OSX library: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrtexlib.asp